# How to save object in firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I Couldn't add an object to firebase realtime database. I tried the following code. But when this code  executes **userRef.child("Users").child(Integer.toString(random.nextInt(100))).setValue(newUser);** 
my app crashes.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference userRef;
    EditText nameEditText;
    EditText passEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        passEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passEditText);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        //        signInAnonymously();
                mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }

                    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
                    }
                });
    }
    public void createUser(View view){

        Random random = new Random();



        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();



        String userN = String.valueOf(nameEditText.getText());
        String pass = String.valueOf(passEditText.getText());


        UserDetails newUser = new UserDetails(userN,pass);

        userRef.child("Users").child(Integer.toString(random.nextInt(100))).setValue(newUser);


    }
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class UserDetails{

    public String userName;
    public String password;

    public UserDetails(){

    }

    public UserDetails(String userName, String userPass){

        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = userPass;
        Log.i("Check", this.userName);

    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
}
```

This is the logcat error message.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.crossappfactory.username, PID: 20144
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
                   Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid key: this$0. Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaiw.zziv(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaiw.zzau(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
at com.crossappfactory.username.MainActivity.createUser(MainActivity.java:63)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: For proper parsing your UserDetail model use the same parameters so replace userPass with password or vice versa. Just use the same naming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is simple, mark the `UserDetails` class as static, so the compiler doesn't generate the extra field:

```
public static class UserDetails {
```

*Explanation of why this is needed, in case you're interested.*

The error message says what's wrong, but it's a bit hard to parse in this case: "Invalid key: this$0. Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'"

It says `this$0`, which is a reference to your `UserDetails` object. The `$0` indicates that its an inner class of the `MainActivity`. When you make an inner class, instances of that class get an extra hidden field referring to their containing object, so that you can say `this.MainActivity` from within the code of `UserDetails`. But the Firebase SDK cannot handle this extra, hidden field, so it raises an exception.

Comment: Declaring the class as static enabled to add the object in the firebase.

Comment: How to deal with it with Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating a random number, try using **push()** also Where are you calling your createUser method ? and can you add the logcat details when your app crashes, that would make it easier to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I call the createUser() method from the Submit button from the activity. I also tried with the **push() ** method. I doesn't work either.

Comment: can you paste your logcat details in the question?

Comment: `Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid key: this$0. Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']' ` this may be causing the error, can you check if your data doesn't contain any of that ?

Comment: I tried Logging my username & password. They all were simple Strings. No Special characters.

Comment: `String userN = String.valueOf(nameEditText.getText());` instead of this try  `String userN = nameEditText.getText().toString();`

Comment: I tried logging the userN. It's a perfect String. I  don't think there is an issue with it. I tried saving them as individual Strings. It works. But as an object(POJO), it doesn't save. I get those errors. I'm pretty not sure what's wrong.[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#basic_write)   I followed trying every possible method. Still I couldn't. Ended up saving all the fields seperately.